# If $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) g(x) dx=0$ with $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$, can I integrate term by term?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose $\int_{a}^{b} f(x,l) g(x) dx=0...(1)$ with Taylor series of $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$, where $a_n$ depends upon parameter $l$. I want to construct non-zero bounded integrable function $g(x)$.

Since we are on finite interval, series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n g(x)$ converges to $f(x)g(x)$ uniformly(?), can I integrate term by term?

Then problem reduces to construction of $g(x)$ such that $\int_{a}^{b}x^n g(x) dx=0$ for $n=0,1,2...$ which I can do. My problem is with integrating term by term, can I construct $g(x)$ in this way?

Comment: If you have uniform convergence, then yes. But in general, no.

Comment: also, what does $l$ have to do with anything?

Comment: $\sum_{n} a_n x^n$ converges to $f(x)$ uniformly on the interval $[a,b]$ if $|a| < R$ and $|b|<R$, where $f$ is analytic in the disk $\{x: |x| < R\}$ (it may or may not converge uniformly if $|a| = R$ or $|b| = R$).  Then, $g$ being integrable, $\sum_n a_n \int_a^b x^n  g(x) \; dx = \int_a^b f(x) g(x)\; dx$ by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @mathworker21, my coefficients $a_n$ depend upon parameter $l$. I thought it wouldn't be harmful to mention it here.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks!